# Getting a "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" warning when dereferencing char *

Tags: c

I have this node:

```
struct Node {
    char *name;
};
```

This is my add function:

```
void add(char **names) {
        struct Node *ch = create(names[0]);
}
```

This is my create function:

```
struct Node *create(const char *name) {
        char *c_pt = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name));
        *c_pt = name;
        struct Node ch;
        ch.name = *c_pt;
        struct Node *ch_ptr = &ch;
        return ch_ptr;
}
```

But when I do this I get a warning saying `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` (points to the line `*c_pt = name;` and `ch.name = *c_pt;`). I initially just used `char *name` instead of `const char *name` but when creating multiple nodes, the name of all the nodes ends up being the name of the last node created.

Comment: `*c_pt` has a type of `char`.

Comment: Note that you're (a) trying to return a pointer to a local variable, which is UB and (b) when you malloc a C string the length needs to be `strlen(name) + 1`.

Comment: Whatever you do, **don't add a cast** to silence the warning.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh, and name has type `const char`? Then where does the pointer and integer come in in the warning message `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`?

Comment: `name` is a *pointer*. `const char *name`

Comment: `*c_pt` is an integer type (`char`) but `name` is a pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah ok, so I dereferenced `name` like so: `*c_pt = *name;` but the warning message still exists and points to the line `ch.name = *c_pt;`. But am I not dereferencing `*c_pt`? Edit: Going to try using strcpy to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Insufficient memory allocate for the *string*.

   ```
   malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name));  // bad
   ```
2. The pointer is copied and not the *string*.  This is also causing the "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast".  `name`  is a pointer and `*c_pt` is a `char`. Anyways, not the right way to copy a string.

   ```
   *c_pt = name; // bad
   ```
3. Function returns pointer to local variable

   ```
   struct Node ch;
   ...
   struct Node *ch_ptr = &ch;
   return ch_ptr; // bad
   ```

---

Allocate memory for `struct Node` and the *string*

```
struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
size_t sz = strlen(name) + 1;
char *s = malloc(sz);
if (n==0 || s==0) {
  free(n);
  free(s);
  return NULL; // failure indication
}
```

Copy the data

```
memcpy(s, name, sz);  // or strcpy(s, name).  I find memcpy faster for long strings
n->name = s;
```

Return the node pinter

```
return n;
```

Comment: `void add(char **names) {
        struct Node *ch = create(names[0]);
}` likely messed up too.  Unclear as to coding goals.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the failing line is this

```
*c_pt = name;
```

Name is of type `const char *`, *c_pt is of type `char`. You cant assign one to the other. I think you are trying to copy the passed in string to something. But then you make a local node object assign things to it and then return it; you cant do that either (Node ch will disappear at the end of the function). I think you need something like this

```
struct Node *create(const char *name) {
        struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        n->name = strdup(name);
          return n;
}
```

for those non posix systems out there.

```
n->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(n->name, name);
```

with the usual caveats about checking mallocs return value

Comment: `strdup()` is a POSIX function, not a standard C function.

Comment: Would using strcpy instead of strdup be similar?

Comment: @Barmar indeed it is POSIX, i bet 10c (or maybe even 25) that the system he is on supports it

Comment: strdup combines malloc, strlen and strcpy and safety checks for you https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?strdup(3)

Comment: @pm100 I get a `error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct Node’)` pointing to `n->name` on both the malloc and strcpy lines. I tried changing it to just `n.name` but then when I create two nodes, the name of the second node gets assigned to both nodes.

Comment: that cos you have struct Node n instead of struct Node *n on the first line